# MySQL WHERE query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem in this code, I'm taking information from two tables and "where news_id=$dz" is not working. [Here is the page](http://novators.ge/pages/1.php) which include this code.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT dz,title FROM dzeglebi where raioni='ყვარლის მუნიციპალიტეტი' && mxare='kaxeti' ORDER BY title ASC", $db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array ($result);

printf(
       "<h2><li>
       <strong><a href='../../dzeglebi.php?id=%s'>%s</a>
       </strong></li></h2>",$myrow["dz"],$myrow["title"]);


function FetchImage($id)
{
    $images=array();
    $x=0;
    $d=mysql_query("select * from `images` where news_id=$dz");
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($d))
    {
        $images["big"][$x]=$data["image"];
        $images["small"][$x]=$data["small"];
        $x++;
    }   
return $images;
}
function CountImages($id)
{
$d=mysql_query("select * from `images` where news_id=$dz");
return mysql_num_rows($d);  
}
$imgs=FetchImage($id);

 for($i=0;$i<CountImages($id);$i++)
{
echo'

 <img src="../'.$imgs["big"][$i].'" >';
}



?>
```

Comment: What's the expected vs actual output?

Comment: You should connect to the $db at first. In functions you cant access $dz. In php inside functions you can access only arguments and local variables. So you should pass $dz az a function argument. (Or access it as a global variable, but passing as an argument is a better way.)
Probably there are others issues also...

Comment: You have `$id` parameter in `FetchImage($id)` and `CountImages($id)` and using where on `where news_id=$dz` there should be `$id`

Comment: Check your $db variable

Comment: I understand you but I want to this that "news_id"=$dz how can I do this?

Comment: I understand you but I want to this that "news_id"=$dz how can I do this? for examle when I write the number of $dz  news_id=52 everything works, and I want that however write code. you understand me?

Answer (score 1):

`function CountImages($id)
{
$d=mysql_query("select * from images where news_id=$dz");` - here you should use $id

next problem: - DO NOT USE `for($i=0;$i<CountImages($id);$i++)` change it to

```
$len = CountImages($id);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
```

because you do not need to perform SQL query for each FOR iteration, or even remove it - as you have $images array, iterate over it

next problem:

```
$d=mysql_query("select * from `images` where news_id=$id");
return mysql_num_rows($d);
```

DO NOT USE `mysql_num_rows`, use SQL `count(*)` - because it will send only 1 number from mysql to php, instead of whole result set

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st query, change `&& mxare='kaxeti'` by `AND mxare='kaxeti'`.
Also, in functions `FetchImage` and `CountImages`, change `news_id=$dz` by `news_id=$id`